# Returning objects from another thread?

Tags: c#, wpf

Trying to follow the [hints laid out here](http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=34), but she doesn't mention how to handle it when your collection needs to return a value, like so:

```
    private delegate TValue DequeueDelegate();
    public virtual TValue Dequeue()
    {
        if (dispatcher.CheckAccess())
        {
            --count;
            var pair = dict.First();
            var queue = pair.Value;
            var val = queue.Dequeue();
            if (queue.Count == 0) dict.Remove(pair.Key);
            OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove, val));
            return val;
        }
        else
        {
            dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new DequeueDelegate(Dequeue));
        }
    }
```

This obviously won't work, because `dispatcher.BeginInvoke` doesn't return anything. What am I supposed to do?

Comment: That blog post is 4 years old and they still haven't fixed it :(

Comment: +1 I'll be interested to see the answers to this question because I need to do something similar in a project of my own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `Invoke` in place of `BeginInvoke`. This will run it on the dispatcher's thread, but will execute synchronously and return the result returned by the delegate.

If you don't need the result immediately, hold onto the `DispatcherOperation` returned by `BeginInvoke`. When you do need the result, call the operation's `Wait` method and, if it returns `DispatcherOperationStatus.Completed`, read the `Result` property.

Comment: Oh... didn't realize `Invoke` would return the result to me :)